# falla conexión ssh por cambio de puerto

Tags: linux, ssh, puertos

Estoy teniendo el siguiente problema: cambio el puerto de la conexión `ssh` (como parte de un ejercicio de clases) utilizando tanto el comando `semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 27960` o por el archivo `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` luego reinicio el servicio, el tema es que intento conectarme desde otra `VM` y me da error de conexión `Connection refused` ni con el parámetro -p para el puerto por defecto ni para el seteado arriba. Agradezco su tiempo.

Comment: Te intentas conectar desde la otra maquina como root? muchas veces no deja si eres root por que hay una opcion que es allow root login dentro del sshd y tiene que estar en permitido

Comment: No, no intento como root, ya que en el `sshd_config` la línea `PermitRootLogin` está en `no`. Igualmente ahora me da un error de permiso para la copia de la calve pública

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se que distribución utilizas pero generalmente se activa un firewall que restringe los puertos accesibles. Asegúrate que el 27960/tcp está permitido (`iptables -L`, aunque según la distro puede ser diferente).

En caso de usar iptables, deberías poder hacer

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport 27960 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Indica los valores correctos para la interfaz (`-i eth0`) y la red (-s 192.168.0.0/24).

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, pero el error estaba en la interfaz entre el teclado y la silla... en modo usuario, olvidé comentar la línea `PasswordAuthentication no`  del `sshd_config` para permitir que esa primer conexión que es para pasar la `clave pública` pidiera la contraseña al usuario como debe ser la primera vez, para luego descomentar y que sea por autenticacion de clave. Utilizo CentOS 7. Y es un buen dato lo de `iptables -L`, puede servir en el futuro. Gracias de nuevo.